# Imagick Code - ImageMagick not working

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Hello People here is my code below...

```
    $width = 1200;
    $height = 100;
    $output="C:\wamp\www\latest\im\arc.gif";

    try
    {
    $pixel = new ImagickPixel( "lightblue" );
    $text = 'srinivas';
    $arcArray = array(360);


    $draw1 = new ImagickDraw();
    $draw1->setFont('Arial');
    $draw1->setFontSize( 120 );
    $draw1->setGravity( Imagick::GRAVITY_WEST );

    $draw2 = new ImagickDraw();
    $draw2->setFont('Arial');
    $draw2->setFontSize( 120 );
    $draw2->setGravity( Imagick::GRAVITY_EAST );

    $im1 = new Imagick();
    $im1->newImage($width, $height, $pixel);
    $im1->annotateImage($draw1, 0, 0, 0, $text);
    $im1->setImageVirtualPixelMethod( Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_WHITE );
    $im1->distortImage( Imagick::DISTORTION_ARC, $arcArray, false );


    $im2 = new Imagick();

    $im2->newImage($width, $height, $pixel);
    $im2->setImageVirtualPixelMethod( Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_WHITE );
    $im2->distortImage( Imagick::DISTORTION_ARC, $arcArray, false );
    $im2->annotateImage($draw2, 0, 0, 0, $text);


    $frame = new Imagick();
    $frame->readImageBlob($im2);
    for ($i = 1; $i < 3; ++$i) {

        $frame = new Imagick();
         $GIF = new Imagick();
        $frame->readImageBlob(${'im'.$i});
        $frame->setImageDispose(2);
        $frame->setImageDelay(100);
        $GIF->addImage($frame);
        $GIF->setImageDelay(100);

    }
    $frame->writeImages("C:\wamp\www\latest\im\arc.gif" , true);


    }

    catch(Exception $e)
    {
            echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Iam getting exception error message `Zero size image string passed` what iam trying to do is very simple,Iam creating two images one with the position `$draw1->setGravity( Imagick::GRAVITY_WEST );` and the other text with the position `$draw1->setGravity( Imagick::GRAVITY_EAST );` , within the same arc created...how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with sample code provided.

**First**

Image `$im2` will need to call `annotateImage` before `distortImage`, or your text will float outside of the arc

```php
$im2->annotateImage($draw2, 0, 0, 0, $text);
$im2->distortImage( Imagick::DISTORTION_ARC, $arcArray, false );
```

**Second**

The error message of "Zero size image string passed" will occur, as `$im2` hasn't been given any format/context. Such that `(string)$im2` will result in an empty string. Fix this by setting the image format

```php
$im2->setImageFormat('gif');
// ...
$frame->readImageBlob($im2);
```

The behavior of `Imagick::readImageBlob(Imagick)` is a little confusing to read. A clean solution would be to define the images blob.

```php
$blob = $im2->getImageBlob();
$frame->readImageBlob($blob);
```

**Third**

I'm also confused by the `for` loop. Whatever you've declared as `$frame` seems to be overwritten with each iteration, and the `$GIF` images doesn't appear to be doing anything. I'll assume you simply want to create an animated gif; which, would only require one instance of `$frame`.

```php
$frame = new Imagick();
$im2->setImageFormat('gif');
$frame->readImageBlob($im2->getImageBlob());
for ($i = 1; $i < 3; ++$i) {
  $frame->addImage(${'im'.$i});
  $frame->setImageDelay(100);
}
$frame->setImageDispose(2);
$frame->setImageIterations(0);
$frame->writeImages("C:\wamp\www\latest\im\arc.gif" , true);
```